# Resources on numerically solving a stochastic Navier Stokes Equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-pde

I know these types of questions don't have definitive answers, but I need some assistance. I would like to do some numerical experiments (preferably in python, but any language is fine) for my thesis involving a stochastic Navier Stokes system, but I really don't know where to begin. I've found a lot of sources (with code) for the deterministic equations, but I'm mostly just finding theoretical papers on the stochastic version.

Essentially, I need to numerically estimate the probability of some events which involve the solution to the Stochastic NSE. As such, I’d need to numerical solve them.

I wouldn't mind writing the code myself of course, but all the papers I find seem "cutting edge" which I'm currently not too interested in; perhaps after I get acquainted with the basics.

If there's any standard source on this material, please let me know.

Comment: You might be better off asking this on [scicomp stackexchange.](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Also, someone has done a dissertation on it [here.](https://publikationen.uni-tuebingen.de/xmlui/bitstream/handle/10900/49705/pdf/diss_main_pub.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y)

Answer (score 0):

There is the book `An introduction to computational stochastic PDEs' by Lord, Powell and Shardlow. It discusses all the basics on how to simulate stochastic PDEs, including examples with the (2d) Navier-Stokes equations. On [Gabriel Lord's website](https://www.macs.hw.ac.uk/~gabriel/ICSPDE.html), all the codes from the book are available to download.